# PDF to JPEG conversion using Ghostscript - Not Proper

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I am trying to convert following PDF to JPEG using Ghostscript 9.14.

PDF - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1LA_arF4NqmWlFKbGpxTnItdFE/view

Command:

```
gswin64 -sDEVICE=jpeg -r600x600 -dUseCIEColor=true -sOutputFile=e:\\Watch.jpg ^
        -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE e:\\Watch.pdf
```

Output JPEG is missing few colors from original PDF - especially the shiny gold colors in upper watch band and dial is not coming proper.

Can someone please guide me the correct parameter from Ghostscript that will resolve this?

Comment: Attached? Not seeing it.

Comment: Can you please check the PDF link in the post?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204629/best-way-to-produce-colour-correct-raster-from-a-pdf-or-ps-with-ghostscript

Comment: thanks. but it is not  helping ...

Answer (score 1):

This has already been raised as a bug report at:

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695975

I very much doubt if asking questions here is going to get you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You convert PDF to JPEG and expect the colors to be preserved?

Forget it!

Why? JPEG is a "lossy" format. It will (almost) never preserve the original colors. It can only "almost-preserve" colors if you apply color management methods (which involves the use of correct ICC color profiles matching your hardware) to your workflow. But JPEG output will be lossy anyway, leading to some typical artifacts occuring very visibly around sharp edges.

If you want a better image format, use PNG output. But also do apply color management when converting...

---

A few additional hints, about how you *may* be able to improve output:

1. Add **`-dJPEGQ=95`** to your command line parameters. This will set the default JPEG quality to 95% and reduce the JPEG artifacts.
2. Use **`-sDEVICE=jpegcmyk`** in case your PDF used CMYK color space. Because `-sDEVICE=jpeg` uses RGB color space, this would minimize all color changes which were due to the CMYK->RGB transformation.

I also noticed (from running `pdfinfo -meta` on your PDF) that the PDF may be using Pantone colors -- specifically: *PANTONE Warm Gray 11*,  *PANTONE Cool Gray 2* and  *PANTONE 200 C*.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know how to convert PDF created using Pantone colors to JPEG/PNG.